# return text from database without html code

Tags: php, html, database, tags

I have a text in my database with html tags to make the direction from right to left. and I am looking for a way to get the text from the database without the html tags.

this is how my text looks in the database:

```
<span dir="rtl"> ما هي تقنية GPS؟</span >
```

and I want to get it just like this:

```
ما هي تقنية GPS؟
```

I am using this code to get the text:

```
<?php echo  $text_db; ?>
```

Comment: have you tried `strip_tags` already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to get rid of HTML structure from a string, the quickest you can use is `strip_tags($string)` - https://php.net/strip_tags